# How to decide which MM lens to use?

Tags: lens, nikon, lens-recommendation, nikon-d5600

I recently purchased Nikon D5600 with dual lens.

It has come with:

1. AF-P: 18-55 mm, and
2. AF-P: 70-300 mm lens

I was just going through Nikon School videos and it was showing one 18-105 mm lens.

I am puzzled. How to decide which MM lens to use in which situation? I usually want to shoot landscapes and wildlife. Which lens is suitable for these specifically?

Comment: I'd suggest taking photos at 18 and 300mm. You'll understand the difference very quickly.

Comment: That's like asking on the car stack exchange site (if there is one) that I recently bought a new car - how do I drive it?

Comment: [Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/) – [Are driving questions on-topic?](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am puzzled. How to decide which MM lens to use in which situation? I usually want to shoot landscapes and wildlife. Which lens is suitable for these specifically?

Most people associate wide angle shots with landscape photography. However, here's [a whole tip article](https://www.photographytalk.com/landscape-photography/7218-6-tips-for-landscape-photography-with-a-telephoto-lens) on using a telephoto for landscape.

Most people associate telephoto shots with wildlife. However, here's a [whole tip article](https://www.slrlounge.com/wildlife-photography-wide-angle-lens-impact-getting-subject-surroundings/) on using a wide angle for wildlife.

You'll get more results and examples by searching for "telephoto landscape photography" and "wide angle wildlife photography."

As far as the focal length is concerned, there is no one best for anything. Photography is an art form and, as such, the product of a shot is whatever you want it to be. Now, *if you want it to be wide*, then you'll use a wide angle lens. And *if you want it to be close*, like shooting a headshot on a lion, then you'll need to use a telephoto lens.

At the end of the day, use whatever focal length you need to get the shot framing that you want. If you run out of focal length, then physically move closer or further away until you get the framing that you want.

Answer (score -1):

You must use the ol’ [Native American photographic framing stone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_rock)

If Stone is too big in frame, use smaller mm.

If Stone is too small in frame, use bigger mm.

Simple really.

Comment: Although, you could also say, if stone is too big, go farther away, and if stone is too small, get closer.

Comment: @twalberg Aka ZWTF. Zoom With Your Feet

Comment: @twalberg ah, you have learned from grizzled elder, Pixel Peeping Prime

Comment: Consider appending this answer to your other answer?

Comment: @xiota what purpose would it serve? This was made in jest and the community has decided it didn't like the joke. I'm fine with that. It'll probably get deleted at some point and tbh, I'm surprised it hasn't. The other answer was legit and can stand alone.

Comment: Moderators appear to be on strike... Why not delete it yourself if you expect it to be deleted someday?

Comment: @xiota because I like humor. Other people (mods/community vote) want to keep this place square, that's okay. Doesn't mean that I won't be me while I'm here. Definitely doesn't mean that I'll bend to other's will. You do you, as the saying goes.

Comment: Then why not append it to your other answer?